# Include Xamarin.iOS when adding a new Xamarin.Forms PCL to solution

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I added a new Xamarin.Forms Portable Class Library to my Xamarin.Forms solution today. The project included the Xamarin.Forms nuget package and assembly reference; it did not however include Xamarin.iOS.

I can see why this wouldn't be included, as it's unclear as to which platform you might be targeting with this PCL. I did go into

```
~/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/9.0.1.29/lib/mono/Xamarin.iOS/
```

directory and add the Xamarin.iOS.dll assembly directly. This seems to work while in debug; in Release mode I've had weird oddities with my PCL library types not being found when needed during DI resolution. This approach also breaks when I update Xamarin.iOS, I have to manually update this assembly reference.

Is there a way to add Xamarin.iOS without having a hard dependency on that specific version, in that path?

Comment: On iOS project, you should check **References** folder, not **Packages** folder. If you don't still have Xamarin.iOS reference, please update the Xamarin for latest stable version and repoen it.

Comment: I have done so, still nothing under references. Edit references does not list Xamarin.iOS as an optional assembly I can add.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a new project for xamarin forms in VS 2013 from New Project -> Mobile apps. The following is the screen shot of the new project screen :

[image]

And here is the screen shot of my solution it created for me:

[image]

All the dependency have been added via Nuget and are updated via the same.

If you are using Xamarin Studio in windows, then it might not create the iOS project for you.

Comment: I am using Xamarin Studio on OSX. The initial Xamarin.Forms iOS project was created with the Xamarin.iOS assembly. When I created a new Xamarin.Forms PCL though, the Xamarin.iOS assembly was not included. A NuGet search doesn't turn up any Xamarin.iOS results either